# How to handle Quickblox session expiration?

Tags: javascript, quickblox

In quickblox, the [session expires two hours after the last request](https://docsdev.quickblox.com/javascript/Getting_started.html#Session_expiration). So to handle this situation I have used the code

```
config.on.sessionExpired = function(next,retry){
})
```

and passed  the `config` in `QB.init`

```
config.on.sessionExpired = function(next, retry) {
    console.log("============session renewal")
    var user = self.get('user')
    QB.chat.disconnect()
    QB.createSession({ login: user.login, password: user.pass }, function(err, res) {
        if (res) {
            // save session token
            token = res.token;
            user.id = res.user_id
            self.get('user').token = token
            QB.chat.connect({ userId: user.id, password: user.pass }, function(err, roster) {
                // Do something   
            })
        }
    })
}
QB.init(QBApp.appId, QBApp.authKey, QBApp.authSecret, config);
```

Is this the right way to renew the session by first disconnecting the chat, then creating a new session first and then connecting the chat back again?

I do not want the client to know that the session has expired in quickblox and they have to refresh the page. The chat is a part of the web portal. It is fine if the quickblox takes 2-3 seconds to create a new session token and then connect to chat. By the time, I can show a loader or some message.

I had tried it without the `QB.chat.disconnect()` but then it did not work and sent me `Unprocessable entity 422` error.

Comment: @Daniel Please stop changing the bracket style as it doesn't improve the code in any way and makes the question longer without any gain. It's a matter of style and preferences and doesn't warrant editing. Instead, focus on the question as a whole and fix what needs to be fixed.

Comment: @Shivam there is two way to handle this problem, first, you use `QB.chat.disconnect()` and reinitialize user and second is to check session available or not on each request if session expires then you have to reinitialize it

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem, and i found some solution at QuickBlox Docs

https://docs.quickblox.com/docs/js-authentication#session-expiration

> QuickBlox JavaScript SDK will automatically renew your current session. There is no need to manually call createSession() method. After login, a session is available for 2 hours. When the session expires, any request method will firstly renew it and then execute itself.

And this example from the official documentation:

```
var CONFIG = {
  on: {
    sessionExpired: function(handleResponse, retry) {
      // call handleResponse() if you do not want to process a session expiration,
      // so an error will be returned to origin request
      // handleResponse();

      QB.createSession(function(error, session) {
        retry(session);
      });
    }
  }
};

QB.init(3477, "ChRnwEJ3WzxH9O4", "AS546kpUQ2tfbvv", config);
```